# I want make this(sum) as a list form in python

Tags: python

`marks = [90, 25, 67, 45, 80]
a = marks
print(marks.count(a>=60))`

**I want to see how many students got marks over 60**

Comment: "marks over 60" means `a > 60`, not `a >= 60` which is inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
In [6]: sum(x >= 60 for x in marks)
Out[6]: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

How many scores over 60?

```
>>> marks = [90, 25, 67, 45, 80]
>>> len([score for score in marks if score > 60])
3
```

This uses a list comprehension to create a new list containing only those scores over 60, then the length of the new list tells you have many scores there are above 60.

Another common way is to use `sum()`:

```
>>> sum(1 if score > 60 else 0 for score in marks)
3
```

You can also take advantage of the fact that booleans are ints:

```
>>> sum(score > 60 for score in marks)
3
```

Or, to better your understanding, using a for loop:

```
count = 0

for score in marks:
    if score > 60:
        count += 1

print count
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this one can be helpful too.

Here we are using [`filter`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter) function for getting elements greater or equal to 60 and then using [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function to get no. of elements.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/867409)

```
marks = [90, 25, 67, 45, 80]
print(len(filter(lambda x: x>=60,marks)))
```

Comment: Reason behind downvote will be helpful for me. Who downvoted?

Comment: Apart from this code printing `237`, you also need to import `functools.reduce` in Python 3. That should be a big hint that `reduce()` is no longer favoured. Combining `filter()` with a `lambda` and then `reduce()` is inefficient and less readable than the equivalent list comprehension or by using `sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to include only the marks you care about:

```
marks = [90, 25, 67, 45, 80]
print(len(filter(lambda x: x>=60, marks)))
```